# How to carry out API testing testing using JMeter on API url

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, web-api-testing

I have an API url and body data in xml format.
How to do load testing of available API url using JMeter?.
I need to check the API performance for multiple user login.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan and specify the desired number of threads (virtual users), iterations and test duration

   Below setup will run the request with 10 users for 1 minute:

   [image]
2. Add a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as a child of the Thread Group and specify the URL and the body there:

   [image]
3. You may also need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header

   [image]
4. Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
5. [Generate HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report) and analyze the results

More information:

- [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)
- [Building a WebService Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html)